# angularjs: open a page then only loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My current ionic code able to get data then open the page. However, I want to open the page then only loading to get the data. I want to change the sequence since it takes 10s to load some data.

Here is my code:

```
  $scope.openDetail = function (stock) {
    console.log(stock.symbol);
    $ionicLoading.show();

    //stockCondition
    if(stock.symbol.length<=$scope.stockCondition) {
      $stockDataFactory.getStockDetails(stock).then(
        function success(data) {
          $globalFactory.personalStockData = data.details;
          $globalFactory.personalStockNews = data.news;
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          $state.go("app.page1");

        },
        function error(error) {
          alert(error.message);
          console.error(error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
      );
    }
    else{//WarrentCondition
      $stockDataFactory.getWarrentDetails(stock).then(
        function success(data) {

          $globalFactory.personalStockData = data.details;
          $globalFactory.personalStockNews = {};
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          $state.go("app.page1");
        },
        function error(error) {
          alert("Stocks Not Found.");
          console.error(error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
      );
    }
  };//end
```

In order to open the `$state.go("app.page1");` first, then only loading data, how shall I made changes of my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should show the page1's html templet . 
My approach will be using ng-if="personalStockData" with the $setTimeout() trick to show the data only when it's loaded. looks something like this

```html
//page1 controller
$stockDataFactory.getStockDetails(stock).then(
        function success(data) {

          $setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.personalStockData = data.details;
            $scope.personalStockNews = data.news;
            
          })
        },
        function error(error) {
          alert(error.message);
          console.error(error);
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
      );
```

html

```html
<div>
...
  <div ng-if="personalStockData">
  </div>
  <div ng-if="personalStockNews">
  </div>
...
</div>
```

anyways try not to use global variables, those are really hard to track.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to bring over the `decision` data that are explicit to the current page over to  `app.page1`. For instance `$scope.stockCondition`. I suspect it is the same for`stock.symbol`. Will have to see what `stock` variable is.

There are many ways you can achieve this. Using query string is one option and is also the most conventional way. Some people prefer to store them in `cookies`, not efficient but applies to certain use-cases.

Again, I am not sure what `$state` is. Assuming it is `angular-ui-router`'s statemanager. Then you can achieve this by;

```
$state.go("app.page1", {
    stockCondition: $scope.stockCondition,
    stocksymLen: stock.symbol.length
});
```

Then on `app.page` controller you can retrieve the values of the query string parameters by doing `$state.params.stockCondition`.

Once you have brought the `decision` variables across to the next page. The next step would be to plug them into the `if-else` statement you got from the other page onto `app.page1`.

**Pseudo code:**

```
angular.module('blah')
    .controller('app.page1', function($scope, $state) {
        // on page load
        if($state.params.stocksymLen <= $state.params.stockCondition) {
            // do your REST call
            ...
        else {
            ...
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. With the code as you demonstrate, it fail to open the page. page1.js I just add similar to pseudo code.

Comment: @lotteryman Haha I was hoping the pseudo code would just work because I was typing those blindly from memory. I guess the most important thing is the solution, the concept in solving your problem and glad that it has helped you in some way. Will appreciate greatly if you can mark this as answered many thanks.

Comment: Which part of it is failing? It is pseudo code thou, so you're expected to tweak it. It is difficult to make a runnable example using the exact framework and packages your project uses. I guess the answer is about providing you with an `idea` / `concept` rather than a working piece of code. Hope you understand.